# How to capitalize all first letters of all words in a sentence, which are writen in fully capitalized format. (Using css)

Tags: html, css

**How to capitalize all first letters of all words in a sentence, which are writen in fully capitalized format. (Using css)**

Original : THIS IS A PARAGRAPH

Need like this :  This Is A Paragraph

Comment: Do `text-transform: lowercase;` then `text-transform: capitalize;`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for:

```
text-transform: capitalize
```

see: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use css property

```
.someClass {
 text-transform: capitalize
}
```